# Problem with Joomla urls

Tags: javascript, ajax, joomla, sef

Hi I have problem with url rewrite on my site..My situation is, that the site is fully ajax loaded and I am changing hash in url to navigate within the site..When someone put the hashed url into his browser, it would load correctly..With this I had first problem, with links for example on facebook and to with copied links on the site..These links are only SEF urls produced by joomla, so I when people comes to the site for example from facebook with this link, I have to parse it and change to the hashed on..Simply it has to be consistent..It all is fully working, but today I got another problem with links in newsletter sent from Joomla..These ones arent parsed by Jrouter, so I have another problem with parsing these ones into hashed form..It is getting to be pretty much complicated, si I am asking if someone here know some best practices to get the kind of behaviour to work..

I apologize for my English, its maybe kind obscure:)So below are some links with description, I hope you will get it, and sould help me;)

http://www.designclub.cz/   --base url no problem, when you will click on links the hash would change

http://www.designclub.cz/#en/realizace-prehled --hashed form of url..again without problems

http://www.designclub.cz/index.php/en/design   --nonhashed url but in SEF form..again working

http://www.designclub.cz/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=95:bongio-koupelny&catid=13&Itemid=14 --raw url and here it comes..Joomla would accept it, but there is the non-hash url detection, so there is problem, it will stuck on 404, but it is not the main point..It is easy to fix..but I need to parse it into hashed one..I hope you understand..Normally I would be able to parse into correct form, but there is problem, that in SEF url are names od sections and categories insteas id's in nonSEF url..And I really dont want to requets these names from database..it is possible, but it is too horrible:)

So again sorry for this mashup of czenglish and thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 0):

So already solved..It isnt perfect, but who cares:D Now I am detecting the ? position in url as condition to reparse it..If is question mark in url I let it be and change on next ajax request(my links which from can be done ajax request have all the sef url, so I can simply parse it into hashed form)